# I want change wav file 16 kHz 16 bit to 8 kHz 16 bit mono C# NAudio

Tags: c#, validation, post, naudio

Code not working, please check out and sey me what i wrong writing?! please help.

```
            openFileDialog openFileDialog = new openFileDialog();

            openFileDialog.Filter = ("Wave Files (*.wav)|*.wav|All Files (*.*)|*.*");

            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;


            WaveFileReader reader = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(dpmFileDestPath);

            WaveFormat newFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);

            WaveFormatConversionStream str = new WaveFormatConversionStream(newFormat, reader);

            try
            {
                WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("C:\\Konvertierten_Dateien.wav", str);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", ex.Message));
            }
            finally
            {
                str.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Konvertieren ist Fertig!");
        }
```

this is a code and not working.

Comment: *How* is it "not working"? Do you get an exception? If yes, what is the exact message? The stack trace of the exception should even tell you *where* something went wrong. If you don't get an exception, how does the result differ from what you expected. (Since you're german, and your english doesn't seem to be that good yet: *Wie genau* funktioniert es nicht? Gibt es eine Fehlermeldung? Falls ja, schreib bitte den genauen Text der Meldung. Der Stacktrace müsste dir sogar genau sagen, *wo* der Fehler auftritt. Falls nicht, was läuft sonst schief? Bitte auf Englisch antworten.)

Comment: @Corak I really appreciate your willingness to help, but Stack Overflow is an [English-only website](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - fair enough. But since OPs question was in english, I think the [official policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) was not harmed (it's only talking about initial questions). I used a comment to ask for further information about the question in english and provided a rough translation for it with the explicit note to please answer in english. I don't see any problem with that if it helps the OP to make his question more clear in less time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change channel count and sample rate at the same time, do it in two steps. E.g. first go stereo to mono, then go 44.1kHz to 8kHz. Without seeing the WaveFormat of your incoming file though or the exception you get, I can't say exactly what the issue is.